# Bash process substitution: what does `echo >(ls)` do?

Tags: bash, echo, ls, process-substitution

Here is an example of Bash's process substitution:

```
zjhui@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ echo >(ls)
/dev/fd/63
zjhui@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ abs-guide.pdf
```

Then I get a cursor waiting for a command.

`/dev/fd/63` doesn't exist. I think what happens is:

1. Output the filename used in `/dev/fd`
2. Execute the `ls` in `>(ls)`

Is this right? Why is there a cursor waiting for input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you execute `echo >(ls)`, bash replaces this with `echo /dev/fd/63` and runs `ls` with `/dev/fd/63` connected to its standard input. `echo` does not use its arguments as file names, and `ls` does not use standard input. Bash will write your standard prompt but the output of `ls` comes after it. You can type in any Bash command there, you just lost the visual cue from the prompt, which is further up the screen.

`echo >(ls)` is not something that is likely to ever be useful.

Comment: I just want to understand the Process Substitution from this example, Thank you for your answer